# How to create a dynamic interface?

Tags: angular, interface

This is how I call a service:

```js
save(values: any): Observable<any> {
  return this.httpClient.put(environment.apiBaseUrl, values)
}
```

Instead of `any`,  I want the generic of `Observable` to be an interface but my problem is that the API returns a very dynamic object. So it could be:

```json
{
    "id": 4,
    "status": "ok"
}
```

or it could be:

```json
{
    "errors": {
        "serviceName": "Has no value",
        "hourlyRate": "Value should not be 0",
        "recipientEmail": "Has no value"
    },
    "status": "bad"
}
```

Especially, the errors could be more or less.

So should I create a dynamic interface? If so, how? Otherwise, what's the alternative?

Comment: if you know all attributes this object could have, you can use the '?' in the interface, this will make your attributes optional

Comment: You can use multiple different interfaces. Like for the example Observable<ResponseOk | ResponseError>

Answer (score 0):

Since I know all the attributes of the object, I created optional attributes (thanks for the advice to RenanSchwyz!).

```js
export interface Response {
  id?: number,
  status: string,
  errors?: Errors
}

export interface Errors {
  contractorEmail?: string
  serviceName?: string,
  hourlyRate?: string,
  recipientEmail?: string,
  title?: string
  services?: string
}
```